# Is it possible to setup VLAN on host without NIC hardware support?

Tags: linux-networking, vlan

We have a group of clients connect to an Arista switch with DHCP enabled. And we want to setup an additional private VLAN so that those clients can communicate to each other through pre-defined static IPs. So that those communication can still happen when DHCP is not working for any reason.

I was able to setup trunk VLAN on switch side with help from internet as below:

```
#show vlan
VLAN  Name                             Status    Ports
----- -------------------------------- --------- -------------------------------
1     default                          active    Et12, Et13, Et51
99    StaticIPVLAN                     active    Et12, Et13
```

And on host side, eth0:0 will be on vlan1 and eth0:1 on vlan99.

However, for our client machines to recognize tagged VLAN traffic I was told that host NIC hardware support is required. A colleague told me HW support might not be needed since it can be done with driver along. But I can not find any information on that google. Is that possible to do from host side(Linux environment)?

Thanks

Comment: The frame is typically checked for integrity by the hardware, and the VLAN tag adds four octets to the frame, possibly creating an oversized frame that will be dropped by the hardware. A normal frame has a maximum size of 1518 octets, but the VLAN tag would make that size be 1522 octets, too large for a NIC that does not recognize a tagged frame.

Comment: Thanks, so NIC hardware support is required otherwise packets will be dropped if I read it correctly.

Comment: Not all frames are of the maximum size, but you will not know if smaller frames work, and many frame would be of the maximum size. A lot of hardware on hosts/servers now does support VLANs. I'm not sure how you determined that is the case.

Answer (score 1):

This is a rather dubious solution to a potential problem. Nobody in the real world would ever do this.

If you're going to create a separate VLAN just for the purpose of assigning a static ip address to the clients in case the DHCP server isn't working, then why not just assign them a static ip address in the first place and forget this nonsense?

**OR**

Why not use a robust and reliable DHCP server?

---

At any rate, the clients don't need to support VLAN tagging. The switch will take care of forwarding the frames to the appropriate switch port based on the switchport VLAN membership.

Comment: We intend to use private vlan for debug/management purpose and not as a backup of network of DHCP. So when vlan1 network is offline, we can still reach other clients on the same switch given we have access to one of unit.

I thought client need NIC to differentiate traffic from various vlans in the case of trunk vlan port. Even thought switch creates tag, client NIC need to recognize it. Am I wrong about this?